# CSS layout footer DIV disappear with 100% height

Tags: css, layout, height

I'm having a problem with my CSS layout.
I tried to managed the problem over the IE and everything works fine, except that the footer container disappeared!.
I tried to re-code the CSS, but the problem still there.
I've been trying for days to fix it, nothing worked.

I don't know what I missed!

Here is what I did `JSFiddle`

Could anyone tell me what I missed?

Comment: What browser and version does this fail

Comment: Hi iSR5 and welcome to Stack Overflow. Where are the html and the css ? I invite you to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

```
the problem is on this part of the css code: 
overflow: hidden;
```

its hidding the footer

Answer (score 0):

When you set the body to have hidden `overflow`, then set the `#container` element to have 100% height, it is pushing the footer container off the bottom of the screen. If you removed the `overflow` declaration (and thus allowed scrolling), you would see the footer right below "the fold".

I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you need a non-scrolling page (usually bad usability practice, FYI), you can use `position` to stick your footer to the bottom of the screen:

```
/* Footer */
#foot{
 width: 800px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #FFD700;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
}
```

See the result: http://jsfiddle.net/euT3x/

Otherwise, remove the `overflow` declaration, or calculate the height of `#container` with javascript after page load.

**Documentation**

- CSS `position` property on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position
- CSS `height` property on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height

Answer (score 0):

Place the Footer DIV into the MID div and modify your CSS with below: [JSFIDDLE link here](http://jsfiddle.net/eyecode/RA2pj/1/)

```
#mid{
    background: #666666;
    width: 563px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#foot{
 width: 800px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #FFD700;
 position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE link here](http://jsfiddle.net/eyecode/RA2pj/1/)